How to switch off boost converter inside 3.7v battery modded device using devices own on/off switch
I'm probably doing something dumb, but I'm trying to learn!. I'm converting my 9v multimeter to use a rechargeable battery with a boost converters, which seems to be working great so far, but I want to add a 12v backlight. My understanding is that boost converters drain the battery while not in use because of the constant conversion, and adding a backlight would require some kind of switch to not just be on all the time. There's (what i think is) a DPDT switch on the board to turn the multimeter on and I was hoping to hook everything up to that, but since the switch is also what is connected to the converter I think it would be creating a loop and kill itself? My electronics knowledge is very slowly growing but is there any way this could be done with diodes or something, I know this would be an easy fix just by adding a switch on the side but I was hoping for a more all in one solution. I tried to google results first but all these conversions seem to just use the 9v terminal to run LEDs off or just use separate buttons. Can anyone point me in the right direction or tell me its impossible



Maybe add a wiring diagram if you can.  You talk about a boost to replace a 9 V battery, and a 12 V backlight, but your picture shows 9 V/15 V.  It's not at all clear how you're proposing to hook everything up with or without the DPDT switch, so a block or wiring diagram may help.

@John D Hi!, sorry I've got it in a weird config right now where the 9v and 15V boost is soldered right onto the boards contact points, Its working fine, but currently have no way to turn it on or off in an elegant way without using a switch somewhere but was hoping i could use the DPDT on the 9v device to turn everything on 

There is an enable (EN) pin which you can enable and disable the boost converter. This will require soldering a wire to the tiny pin on the chip.

To turn it OFF, connect it to GND. To turn ON, connect it to 5V (or a voltage greater than 1.5V). Note that the EN pin is quite robust. It can survive a voltage up to 26V. According to the datasheet, the shutdown current consumption is typically 0.1µA (1µA max).
Edit
Warning: The EN pin is either directly connected to VIN+ (as shown in the left schematic) or weakly pulled up to VIN+ (as in the right schematic).

For either case, the boost converter IC will not respond when you switch OFF. You need to lift the pin or cut the copper trace.

That seems perfect!, but i cant seem to get it working, I'm probably being incredibly dumb but what would the "input supply" be in my case. I've almost each point on the on off switch and its not doing anything

Perhaps I have to lift the pin?

added the EN point to a few spots that had 0.0v then 9v when switched and it seems to force the device to stay on with no way to turn it off unless i desolder the spot...

got it working, after re re re reading the function and realising the pin DOES need to be lifted

Apologies for not warning you earlier. Yes, you need to lift the pin or cut the copper trace.

Sorry diddnt mean to sound like i was blaming you! After reading the function a few times its obvious that the pin needs to be lifted as the trace is in line with the VIN+ going to the 5 IN pin on the chip. Super useful feature its a shame its not on the board in "chose your own" solder point kinda way as cutting it would be difficult because of sharing the 5in trace, Ended up just desoldering it to lift the pin safely. Multimeter and bright backlight is now working great!
